# Getting user input while letting other code run

Tags: python, input

I'm making a Discord client (in old discord.py). Discord requires regular communications or else it will close the connection and subsequently make my program crash. My client requires user input (via input command) for the message which prevents the request from being made and making it crash.

Is there a way to ask for user input and let other code run in the background?

Comment: Don't have time for a full answer but look into the threading module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use threading:

```
from _thread import start_new_thread as thread

def othercode(): # Code which will execute during input
    print("bloop")

def inputcode(): # Code which will recieve input
    global thing
    thing = input("input: ")

thread(othercode) # Start a thread
inputcode() # STart the input script on the main thread
```